# How to ignore URL routing for subdirectories ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

i am routing company names to the their pages with URL routing .NET 4.0

**www.xyz.com/companyname** it works good, but i dont want to route if the page like this

**www.xyz.com/Pages/Company/Products.aspx?id=123** i want to ignore if url start with **"Pages"**

```
    void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Ignore("~/Pages/"); // i tried this but did not work

        routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.Ignore("");
        routes.MapPageRoute(
           "Bayi Sayfa",               
           "{*BayiName}",  
           "~/Pages/HomePage/Default.aspx" 
        );
    }
```

also i tried this

```
routes.Ignore("Pages/");
```

but this is also not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem when i ignored other file extensions

```
   routes.Ignore("{*alljs}", new { alljs = @".*\.js(/.*)?" });
   routes.Ignore("{*allcss}", new { allcss = @".*\.css(/.*)?" });
```

then this line is working

```
   routes.Add(new Route("Pages", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

Comment: there is no code for StopRoutingHandler() which i wrote. it is function which is already defined